# Making list of all possible sums up to a certain value

Tags: python, algorithm, optimization

I need to make an effective algorithm for getting all possible sums (EDIT: pairwise) of elements from one list (including themselves), and storing them into another list up to a certain value.

For instance, if the value is 30, and the list is `[1,2,3,4,5,15,20]`, I want a list that is:

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,30]
```

Right now I have a algorithm that works, yet is extremely ineffective (I need to do this up to 29000:

```
sumlist = [0]*60000
for j in range(0,len(abundlist)):
  for i in range(j,len(abundlist)):
    if sumlist[abundlist[i] + abundlist[j]] == 0: sumlist[abundlist[i] + abundlist[j]] = 1
```

Where I put a 1 if the sum has occurred, in order to avoid equal values.
I have also tried to eliminate all multiples from the abundlist first, but that didn't help at all.

I think I may be approaching this problem wrong. Any suggestions/optimizations/comments would be very helpful.

Comment: The total sum of `[1,2,3,4,5,15,20]` is 50.  Alternatively, the sum of the maximum two entries is 35, not 30. Either way I think you are missing some entries.

Comment: and 35, and 40, and ....

Comment: The OP said they only want sums "up to a certain value", and "the value is 30" in his example.  So 50, 35, 40 ... are irrelevant here.

Comment: should 3+4+20=27 be in the result list?

Comment: Why does your desired list include 1 and 15 (no two numbers sum to these values), but not 16 (which is 1+15)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to initialise lists in python using the first line. And to sum every pait of digits is easy using list comprehension:

```
>>> x=[1,2,3,4,5,15,20]
>>> [i+j for i in x for j in x]
[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 16, 21, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 17, 22, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 18, 23, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 19, 24, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 20, 25, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 30, 35, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 35, 40]
```

If you want to restrict this, you can add a simple filter to the end of the comprehension:

```
>>> [i+j for i in x for j in x if i+j<=30]
[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 16, 21, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 17, 22, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 18, 23, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 19, 24, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 20, 25, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 30, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25]
```

And if they need to be unique, you can covnvert it to a set, then back to a list:

```
>>> list(set([i+j for i in x for j in x if i+j<=30]))
[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 30]
```

However, sets are unsorted, and the conversion back to a list may not neccessarily maintain order, so you can also sort it like so:

```
>>> sorted(list(set([i+j for i in x for j in x if i+j<=30])))
[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 30]
```

### Regarding the efficiency of this:

Here is a fun little test that shows performing the mass sums, including casting to and from sets and lists multiple times. In essence it builds a list of numbers from 1 to 1000 (weighted more towards smaller numbers to match the numbers in the original question), then performs the sums as described above.

Building and running list, and summing it, 100 times takes under 2 seconds.

```
>>> timeit.timeit(
    'x=sorted(list(set([randint(1,i) for i in range(2,1000)])));z=[i+j for i in x for j in x if i+j<=500]',
    setup="from random import randint",number=100)
1.7806868553161621
```

Comment: the OP is asking for all combinations sum, not just pair sum

Comment: Thanks, I've tried this and it worked. However, wouldn't there be any way to avoid the repeats? Because the way it's coded, it is doing twice as many sums as it should be, isn't it?

And sorry for the lack of precision zhangxaochen, I meant pairwise sorry

Comment: @zhangxaochen OPs question is ill-defined. His desired set of sums includes 1 and 15 (no two numbers sum to these values). But not 16 which is 15+1.

Comment: Yes that was a typo, fixed as well.

Comment: @triplebig Regarding doing twices as many sums, thats probably unavoidable. Besides addition is very cheap.